# Remotely connect to Amazon AWS Mysql

Tags: networking, server, ssh, mysql, amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu 14.04. where I installed MYSQL 5.5.

I am trying to connect to the MYSQL running on this instance from my local Windows10 machine running Navicat.

**State of the env:**

3306 is listening

```
netstat -an | grep 3306 -> tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:3306 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN
```

MYSQL is started

```
ubuntu@ip-***-**-**-**:/$ sudo service mysql status
mysql start/running, process 28015
```

select User, Host from mysql.user;

```
| blog             | %         |
| blog             | localhost |


mysql> show grants for 'blog'@'%';
+--------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for blog@%                                |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'blog'@'%'                 |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `blogdb`.* TO 'blog'@'%' |
+--------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

telnet from my PC to the server does not work -> need to sleep. will come back tomorrow :)
```

I am connected to the Ubuntu instance via SSH using a private key.

**The former problem:**

When trying to connect from windows using [Navicat](https://www.navicat.com/products/navicat-for-mysql) to MYSQL running on my AWS instance I get the following error:

***Can't connect to Mysql server on '41.42.434.169' (10061 "Unknown error")*** -> the IP stated here is not mine

The Host name/IP Address I use is the Public IP of my AWS instance.

**This was fixed by commenting the `# bind-address      = 127.0.0.1` in my.cnf**

Now telnet from my PC works

**EDIT**

Now I get the following error:

**Access denied for user blog@myIPprovider.com ( using password: YES )**

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I am not sure *what* exactly is your question. Are you getting an error message when trying to connect to the server? Could you elaborate a bit? :)

Comment: Hi, thx. I am sorry, the question got lost in the explanation :)

Comment: Did you open up the port in AWS security profile for the server?

Comment: Hi, thank you for commenting. I managed to have a successfull telnet from my PC to the server. Now the problem is in the -- Access denied for user blog@myIPprovider.com ( using password: YES ) -- (I dont know if I should not start a new question - it is getting a bit messy here)

Comment: @bc2946088 btw, yes in the instance I created a group also opening the port for this group for mysql - 3306. I opened also for 443 (https), 80(http), 25 (SMTP) and 22 for SSL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For remote access:**

Check etc\mysql\my.cnf to see that the bind-address is not set to 127.0.0.1.
Either set it to 0.0.0.0, or, to be more secure, add your IP address:

```
bind-address      = 127.0.0.1
bind-address      = your_public_ip
```

**Create a user in the mysql table:**

```
CREATE USER 'non-root-user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'any_password_u_like';
CREATE USER 'non-root-user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'any_password_u_like';

GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'non-root-user'@'localhost';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'non-root-user'@'%';
```

**AWS SPECIFIC**

Make sure you have an inbound rule for port 3306